# Angular Drop Down Not Showing Elements

Tags: angular, angular2-template, dropdown

In my html component, I have the following:

```
        <select class="hideLabel form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantType" name="powerPlantType" (change)="selectName();">
          <option selected="" value=""></option>
          <option [ngValue]="powerPlantType" *ngFor="let powerPlantType of powerPlantTypes">
            {{ powerPlantType }}
          </option>
        </select>
```

It displays fine as it can be seen from the screenshot below:

[image]

How do I add a message that says "--Select Type--" text when the page is loaded?

EDIT: Based on the suggestions from the post below, I could still not get it to work: So when the page loads the dropdown is still empty without the intended default test "--Select Type--"

[image]

But the test seem to appear when selcting the drop down!

[image]

I would rather like to have it like this when the page is loaded:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to following:

```
<select class="hideLabel form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantType" name="powerPlantType" (change)="selectName();">
    <option selected="" value="">--Select Type--</option>
    <option [ngValue]="powerPlantType" *ngFor="let powerPlantType of powerPlantTypes">
        {{ powerPlantType }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: It sort of partially works, but I would like this text --Select Type-- to appear when the page is loaded. See my edited post! I have added 2 screenshots that explains the problem that I face when I tried your suggestion!

Comment: I cannot see the edited post , have you added another screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry! Have a look now!

Comment: Have you got an idea?